# How to reduce all value above certain value using Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, raster-calculator

I have a raster with elevations above 2000m that I want to "cut" to 1800m.

I cannot quite figure out the correct string and most simple way to do this in the ArcGIS 9.3 raster calculator.

I tried to ceiling function without much luck; would an expression similar to IF([my_raster]>2000,1800,[my_raster]) do the trick?

Comment: You might be looking for [`con`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Con/009z00000005000000/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a conditional (Con) statement in the raster calculator or the con tool in ArcToolbox. The below statement is evaluated as [IF myrasters > 2000 THEN 1800 ELSE myraster]

```
Con("myraster" > 2000, 1800, "myraster")
```

Comment: Cheers! 
Con([myraster] > 2000, 1800, [myraster]) worked perfectly. Thank you!!